React using custom hook vs helper function to create dynamically colors?
Im creating colors dynamically. Custom hooks are generally for when react features are needed (state, useEffect etc), which I dont need. However, if I dont have a custom cook I cannot use a theme for the colors inside the helper file and would have to hard code the colors, which is less good practice. What is best in this case - using a custom cook or generate colors inside a helper function?
Thanks.
export interface BackgroundColors {
  from: number;
  to: number;
  color: string;
}
const colors: BackgroundColors[] = [
  {
    from: 0
    to: 5,
    color: "red"
  },
  ..
]
const createColor = (value) => {
  //based on value create color
}
const App = () => {
const value = 3;
  return (
    <div style={{backgroundColor: createColor(value)}}></div>
  )
}


Use a helper function for generating dynamic colors since React-specific features (like state or effects) aren't needed. You can still pass the theme or color palette as an argument to avoid hardcoding colors, making it simple and efficient. Custom hooks are unnecessary here.
Update
To pass the theme to the BackgroundColors array, you can pass the theme (or color palette) as a parameter to your createColor function or directly reference the theme object within the helper function. This avoids hardcoding and keeps it dynamic based on the theme.
Here’s an example where you pass the theme to your helper function:
Example
export interface BackgroundColors {
  from: number;
  to: number;
  color: string;
}

const createColor = (value: number, theme: any) => {
  const colors: BackgroundColors[] = [
    { from: 0, to: 5, color: theme.colors.red }, // Use theme colors
    { from: 6, to: 10, color: theme.colors.blue },
    { from: 11, to: 15, color: theme.colors.green },
  ];

  return colors.find((bg) => value >= bg.from && value <= bg.to)?.color || theme.colors.default;
};

// Simulating theme object for this example
const theme = {
  colors: {
    red: "#FF0000",
    blue: "#0000FF",
    green: "#008000",
    default: "#FFFFFF",
  },
};

const App = () => {
  const value = 3;
  const color = createColor(value, theme);

  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: color }}>
      The background color changes based on value!
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;


Thanks. But how can I pass the theme to the array "BackgroundColors"?
